# Count where the value is not missing

Tags: sql, sas

I want to count the occurrences of dates in a column where the value is not missing. So for example, I want to count the number of times a car has been serviced, rather then including the null values where there are no service dates.

I tried the simple count function but it brings all the records. I thought of using 'case' but I am not sure about the syntax. I am using the SAS Enterprise Guide.

sample date

```
id    car     service_Date
1     honda   01/01/2005
2     honda   01/01/2006
3     honda   
4     honda   01/01/2008
5     honda   
6     honda   01/01/2010
```

RESULT: I want to have only 4 as the answer so its not counting the null values.

```
PROC SQL;
CREATE TABLE WORK.QUERY_FOR_CARS AS 
SELECT 
t1.CAR,
t1.ID  
/* SERVICE_DATE */
(count (case when t1.S_DATE is not null then 0 end)) AS SERVICE_DATE
FROM WORK.QUERY_FOR_CAR_SERVICE
GROUP BY t1.S_DATE;
QUIT;
```

I have added the code that I am using. It gives me the count for the dates but also includes where the date value is null.

Comment: You need to include your query, and the SQL dialect.

Comment: You should look into the `WHERE` statement

Comment: what data type is Service_Date?  (I'd assume date but I've seen stranger)

Comment: Beanie, the edit you just made to your question is not helpful (and is syntactically invalid).  Are you looking for a query to return the number of non-missing **S_DATE** values for each **CAR**?

Answer (score 7):

Given a SAS dataset named CARS containing the variables in your example, you can find the number of observations with non-missing values of service_date two different ways in SQL:

```
proc sql;

   select count(service_date) as num_not_missing
   from cars;

   select count(*) as num_not_missing
   from cars
   where service_date is not null;

quit;
```

The first example specifies the service_date variable in the count function, which will ignore missing values.  The second counts all rows after applying the `where` clause.  Both perform identically.

Comment: @xQbert the service is is just a date.

Answer (score 4):

Two options for MS Sql Server:

```
SELECT COUNT([service_Date]) FROM [table1]
```

or

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [table1] WHERE [service_Date] IS NOT NULL
```

For more on `COUNT()`, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

by default count(service_date) excludes null values, as opposite to count(*) which counts all rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could try, `WHERE column != ""` or if you don't have NULL maybe you could use `WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(column) > 3`

Answer (score 0):

Lamak,

There are a few ways to go about this. Here is the method I would use, avoiding PROC SQL.

```
/* Set up example data */    
data   YourTable;
input id car $ service_Date;
informat service_Date mmddyy10.;
format service_Date mmddyy10.;
cards;

1 honda 01-01-2005
2 honda 01-01-2006
3 honda ""
4 honda 01-01-2008
5 honda ""
6 honda 01-01-2010

run;

/* Count non null records */
data work.CountTable(keep=NbrNulls);
 set work.YourTable(where=(service_date ne .)) end=last;
 if last;
 NbrNulls=_N_;
run;
```

Depending on how you were going to use that count, you could add a "call symputx()" function at the end of the last data step to call it as a macro variable elsewhere.

The result is 4.

Answer (score 0):

If it can be from another Proc [(Proc Means)](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi29/240-29.pdf)

```
data have;
 input car $ service_date mmddyy10.;
 format service_date mmddyy10.;
datalines;
honda 01/01/2005
honda 01/01/2006
honda
honda 01/01/2008
honda
honda 01/01/2010
toyota 01/01/2005
toyota 01/01/2006
toyota
toyota 01/01/2008
toyota
toyota 01/01/2010
;

Proc Means N data=work.have noprint; 
 var service_date;
 by car;
 output out=work.want(drop= _type_ _freq_)  n=count;
run;
```